# How to disable filesystem expansion on Ubuntu for desktops?

Tags: filesystem

I flashed [Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) to disk and removed `x-systemd.growfs` from `/etc/fstab` before booting Pi.

`/etc/init.d/resizefs_once` doesn’t exist on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS image.

Filesystem is still expanded somehow.

How can I disable that?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out… `touch /etc/growroot-disabled` fixes unexpected filesystem expansion.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/1947311.

Likely a bug with Ubuntu for desktops.

Comment: There's plenty of questions in AskUbuntu that turn out to be bugs, some even fixed.  Links to the bug in the real bug tracker are good.  Better is a report of what version it is fixed in so people know they need to update (when that's possible).